# Inequality problem one

Tags: inequality

$$-\frac12\le x\le 0\ or\ 0\le x\le \frac14,$$

$$\frac 14\ge x^2\ge 0\ or\ 0\le x^2\le \frac 1{16}$$
Why are the signs reversed in first inequality and not in second after squaring?

Answer (score 1):

$-\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq0$ implies  $0\leq x^2\leq\frac{1}{4}$
because $f(x)=x^2$ decreases on $(-\infty,0]$.

Also, we can understand this by the following way.

For $-\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq0$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{4}-x^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}+x\right)\geq0.$$

Now, the right inequality.

$0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{4}$ implies  $0\leq x^2\leq\frac{1}{16}$
because $f(x)=x^2$ increases on $[0,+\infty)$.

We can understand this by another way:

For $0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{4}$ we obtain:
$$\frac{1}{16}-x^2=\left(\frac{1}{4}-x\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}+x\right)\geq0.$$

Comment: Sorry Michael I put the minus by mistake. Can u explain now after correction.

Comment: @Rajan Singh I fixed and added something. See now.